# Objective C trying to add border to button

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to add a border to some buttons I have. This is what I tried:

```
[areaButton setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[areaButton setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

but I get these errors:

```
No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setBorderWidth'
No visible @interface for 'UIButton' declares the selector 'setBorderColor'
```

What Am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: `areaButton` => `[areaButton layer]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[areaButton.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[areaButton.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
```